# Encapsulating RTOS Queue object in an IQueue custom interface having only static allocation

Tags: c++, architecture, embedded, freertos, rtos

in an embedded component based system, I have a custom interface IQueue that can derive a specific system implementation, for this example, FreeRTOSQueue.

```
class IQueue { ... virtual void push(...) = 0; ... };
class FreeRTOSQueue : public IQueue { ... };
```

I would like to use static allocation only, which I can not do with IQueue. Since it is a component based system, I do not want to instantiate FreeRTOSQueue directly into a system class.

The ideal usage would be something like the following code, which is kinda similar of the FreeRTOS usage.

```
class MyApplication {
public:
    ...

    IQueue queue;

    void init()
    {
        this->queue = this->kernel->createQueue(...);
    }
};
```

I could instantiate the queues as globals and inject into the classes along with kernel instance and other components, but it is not very good because the queue is not a system element, it is an element of that module only.

I would like to hear architecture suggestions on the best approach to make it clean and simple. Please keep in mind it is an embedded system.

obs.: if you think it is not possible, since at some point I need to have some memory allocated for the specific queue class, feel free to point that.

Thank you,

Rafael

Comment: The way this is normally done in embedded is to create a static memory pool. Each time you call the constructor, you get one item from the pool. Each time you call the destructor, you free one. You'll need some error handling when the pool is full.

Comment: I did not want to add logics to it, it was supposed to be only an interface

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a suitable solution for me, I hope it helps anyone who needs something similar.

First, I declared an interface IQueue and forward declared a type Queue

```
class IQueue { ... virtual void push(...) = 0; ... };
class Queue;
```

then, when I declared my IKernel interface, the createQueue method returned by value the Queue object

```
class IKernel { ... virtual Queue createQueue(...) = 0; ... };
```

for the implementation, I declared a FreeRTOSQueue and the Queue class inheriting from it:

```
class FreeRTOSQueue : public IQueue { ... xQueueHandle handle; ... };
class Queue : public FreeRTOSQueue {};
```

the FreeRTOSQueue will contain the xQueueHandle, the same could be extended to semaphores. The kernel createQueue implementation would be:

```
class FreeRTOSKernel : public IKernel {
public:
    Queue createQueue(...)
    {
        Queue q;
        q.handle = xQueueCreate(...);
        return q;
    }
}
```

and, the usage:

```
class MyApplication {
public:
    ...

    Queue queue;

    void init()
    {
        this->queue = this->kernel->createQueue(...);
    }
};
```

I am still thinking about moving the createQueue as an "init" method on the IQueue class, it think it would be cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you right,  what you are looking for is called thread-safe memory pool:
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_pool.

Googling this terms yields tons of acurate designs & implementations, including Boost which whould work for any OS and not just FreeRTOS